# Cannot import name 'type_spec_registry' from 'tensorflow.python.framework' when loading mnist dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running tutorial code from tensorflow's website and it returns the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'type_spec_registry' from 
'tensorflow.python.framework' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\__init__.py)
```

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
```

How to fix this? I have updated tensorflow and keras to their latest versions. I have also tried using `from tensorflow import keras` instead but that did not work either.

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the full error trace (and remove any code that comes *after* the error).

Comment: @Skipper1504, I cannot replicate the error with the given details. It just works. You need to provide more context. Are you using a virtual environment? You can try it under a virtualenv with the TensorFlow library freshly installed and see the results.

Comment: Please provide us some details like which System OS, TensorFlow and python version you are using to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. As I read about it, this error is related to the version of TensorFlow. I intensely recommend updating your Tensorflow version using this command in Terminal:

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

Good Luck.